# Java memory barrier and visibility

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, memory-barriers

I'm confused about what happens exactly when the memory barrier is fired, I thought this is also used for getting cache coherence with main memory, but I ran a test and as result what I thought was wrong.

I have 2 threads, the main and another, I will call them M and T for simplicity.

CASE 1: This works exactly as I expected

If T is waiting on a NOT volatile shared variable and then M changes this value, probably T will not see the changes (because is reading the cache), BUT if T activates the memory barrier then the cache value gets updated with the main memory and the thread can end his job.

CASE 2: This don't work as I expected

NOTE: for making this CASE you need to comment the line with `threadAt.get();` and uncommet the line with `//mainAt.get();`

This case is perfectly identical to the first, BUT the memory barrier is activated in M, I thought that the memory barrier will upload all the caches with the main memory and hence T will see it, but this isn't the case, T goes in a forever loop.

Can someone pls explain what is really happening with this memory barrier?

```
package aaa.testVisibility;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Worker implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AtomicInteger threadAt = new AtomicInteger(0); //<-- Used for activating memory barrier later
        System.out.println("Waiting");
        while (!TestVisibility01.go) {
            threadAt.get(); // <-- memory barrier fired, COMMENT THIS LINE AND UNCOMMENT THE OTHER
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting thread");

    }
}

public class TestVisibility01 {

    public static boolean go = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Worker());
        AtomicInteger mainAt = new AtomicInteger(0);
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Main thread sleep");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        go = true;
        //mainAt.get(); // <-- memory barrier fired, UNCOMMENT THIS LINE AND COMMENT THE OTHER
        System.out.println("Main thread restart");
        t.join();
        System.out.println("Main exit");
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, the thread that modified the memory needs to execute a write barrier to make its changes available. The thread that reads the memory needs to execute the read barrier to see the changes made by others.

Comment: @Arkadiy I the first example I do not do a write barrier, how can it work?

Comment: Some architectures are more optimized than others. It would help if you could provide 2 actual programs rather than `COMMENT THIS` kind of thing, and if you would use the actual thread names.

Comment: BTW, I only see `get()` in your code, not put(). That means you have no write barrier  (unless atomic `get()` is both, I am not sure).

Comment: @Arkadiy They are only 2 lines to bee modified, I think it  is a overkill to rewrite the same program with only 2 different lines.

Comment: @Arkadiy Yeah, with only `get()` in CASE1 apparently it always works fine

Comment: There is no “memory barrier” in the Java specification. If this code happens to do what you intend, it’s just coincidence due to implementation details. This is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: You need to write code in term of synchronization provided by release and acquire operations NOT in term of "barriers".